# How to compare two dates of different format?

Tags: bash, date, timestamp, comparison, utc

Read from an ancient log, date is like this:

```
Wed 31 Oct 2018 08:42:00 AM UTC
```

The other date is like this:

```
12-10-2018 14:37:42
```

which was the best I could get with `date -r ${fname} "+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"`.

Is it possible to compare these dates? The fact that first uses a word for the day discourages me severely. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting dates in above format, then you need to convert 2nd data string to make it parseable by Unix `date` command first. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dt1='Wed 31 Oct 2018 08:42:00 AM UTC'
dt2='12-10-2018 14:37:42'

dt2=$(sed -E 's/^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\2-\1/' <<< "$dt2")
echo "$dt2" # 2018-12-10 14:37:42

# compare EPOCH second values of both dates

if (( $(date -d "$dt1" '+%s') < $(date -d "$dt2" '+%s') )); then
    echo "date1 is less than date2"
else
    echo "date1 is >= than date2"
fi
```

Comment: Wouldn't say I got surprised by you, using regex. :) Any comment on yours and choroba's answer, which one should be used? Or that's primarily opinion based?

Comment: Well if you are getting date formatted as `'12-10-2018 14:37:42'` from some source, then you have no option but to use `sed` first (as I showed) and then compare dates.

Answer (score 3):

Dates are much easier to compare if they follow the `ymdHMS` pattern, because plain old string comparison works:

```
#!/bin/bash
format='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
date1='Wed 31 Oct 2018 08:42:00 AM UTC'
date1=$(date -d "$date1" "$format")

date2=$(date -r "$fname" "$format")

if [[ $date1 < $date2 ]] ; then
    echo "$date1 goes before $date2"
else
    echo "$date1 goes after $date2"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare two dates by creating new instance of your date object for example.

```
var date1 = new Date('Wed 31 Oct 2018 08:42:00 AM UTC');
var date2 = new Date('12-10-2018 14:37:42');
```

this will convert it it to default date format.

Comment: This is Bash. the above syntax seems to be Javascript.

Comment: Ah, @MatiasBarrios, good point (explains why I didn't think of that). Mujahid, maybe you thought this was a Javascript question? :)